# Regex from ... to

Tags: javascript, regex

Simple question I got string that looks like :

```
"This is first sentence, This is bad s3ntence,  This is second sentence, This is third sentence"
```

and I want to get all results that starts from "This is" and ends "sentence" without extra matches

I tried This `is.*?sentence` but it gets me extra match "this is bad s3ntence,  This is second sentence", any way to get only what I need without extra match?

Thanks!

Comment: Define first what is a sentence.

Comment: ok I ve found a way thanks to You marking this as duplicate bro!
(This is((?!This is).)*?sentence)

I think I'd never found it using search because I was not sure what to type! Thanks again!